# Expiry Policy in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, configuration, ignite

This is my Code,

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800")
                .setUserName("ignite")
                .setUserPassword("ignite");
CacheConfiguration cfgc = new CacheConfiguration("myCache");
cfgc.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ofMinutes(6)));
IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg);
```

This shows error on `Duration.ofMinutes(6)`.
How can i set expiry policy in apache ignite CacheConfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `javax.cache.expiry.Duration` instead of `java.time.Duration`.

Here is an example:

```
import javax.cache.expiry.Duration;
...
cfgc.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 6)));
```

Comment: yeahh,, can you share the same example by Python?